# cannot select Available for private distribution to specific organizations on Apple Business Manager or Apple School Manager

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, publish, distribution, apple-business-manager

I would like to publish my apps privately, but when I preparing a submission in app store connect, the radio button is dissable. like picture below
[disabble radio buttton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktw81.png)

The step that I follow like picture below to setup in ABM:
[ABM step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjkiO.jpg)

Comment: You need to complete all of the details in tax and banking including adding a bank account.

Comment: Thank Paulw for the reply, I have go to that section, then I go Paid agreement but the 'agree' button also disable even though I already use admin role. there is caution said, "New agreements are now available for a user with a legal role to accept." and my agreements only show free and paid.